How can I use two different authorization types on two separate graphql type/fields in Appsync?
let's say I want to send a request like this to appsync where book has "apiKey" as the authorization type and reader has "lambda authorizer". How do I send a single api request with two different authorization types?
query {
  book {
    details(bookId: "123") {
      author
    }
  }
  reader {
    firstName
    lastName
  }
}

I tried putting both authorization header "x-api-key" and "authorization" but it seems like appsync is only reading "x-api-key" and ignoring "authorization" when both of them exists.
Tried putting both type of authorization header but appsync is only reading one of them "x-api-key". If I remove "x-api-key" header then the field that uses lambda authorization will work but the field that uses api key will not work and vice versa.
